# Chrome web store shows "No result for 'search-terms'. "

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Whatever I search in Chrome web store, it shows
"No result for 'search-terms'. Make sure all words are spelled correctly, or try a different search."
The following image shows in detail.

[image]

Why this message is shown? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome web store page click up right on Settings icon (gear) and in the drop-down menu select Location. Then from the offered countries select one.
It will work now...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!!! But my country is not available there. I chose "worldwide" and it worked.